# Nothing happens when you click a text

Tags: java, android

The following code displays items from a sql database and performs the necesary operation. For example, clicking on the call calls the number of the employee. I dont want anything to happen when I click on the **Availibility** text. What should I use for that?

```
 if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        employeeNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
        employeeNameText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));

        titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));




        actions = new ArrayList<EmployeeAction>();



        String officePhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("officePhone"));
        if (officePhone != null) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("Call office", officePhone, EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL));
        }

        String cellPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cellPhone"));
        if (cellPhone != null) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("Call mobile", cellPhone, EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL));
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("SMS", cellPhone, EmployeeAction.ACTION_SMS));
        }

        String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
        if (email != null) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("Email", email, EmployeeAction.ACTION_EMAIL));
        }

        String available = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("availability"));
        if (available != null) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("Availability", available, EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL));
        }

        managerId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerId"));
        if (managerId>0) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("View manager", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerFirstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("managerLastName")), EmployeeAction.ACTION_VIEW));
        }

        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE managerId = ?", 
                new String[]{""+employeeId});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
        if (count>0) {
            actions.add(new EmployeeAction("View direct reports", "(" + count + ")", EmployeeAction.ACTION_REPORTS));
        }

        adapter = new EmployeeActionAdapter();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    EmployeeAction action = actions.get(position);

    Intent intent;
    switch (action.getType()) {

        case EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL:  
            Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + action.getData());  
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, callUri); 
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case EmployeeAction.ACTION_EMAIL:  
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("plain/text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{action.getData()});
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case EmployeeAction.ACTION_SMS:  
            Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("sms:" + action.getData());  
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri); 
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case EmployeeAction.ACTION_REPORTS:  
            intent = new Intent(this, DirectReports.class);
            intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", employeeId);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case EmployeeAction.ACTION_VIEW:  
            intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", managerId);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}    

class EmployeeActionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmployeeAction> {

    EmployeeActionAdapter() {
        super(EmployeeDetails.this, R.layout.action_list_item, actions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        EmployeeAction action = actions.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(action.getLabel());
        TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
        data.setText(action.getData());
        return view;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: if you don't want anything to happen, why are you giving it the ACTION_CALL value? did you try replacing this with an option not inside your switch clause?

Comment: I cannot keep it outside the swicth clause as I will have to modify my other codes if I do so. I am new to android. Please suggest some other way. Thanks!

Comment: comment out this line: actions.add(new EmployeeAction("Availability", available, EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL));

Comment: Doing this removes the availability text altogether. I want it to remain. Clicking on it should not do something.

Comment: excellent, so now, instead of "EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL_", place -1 (if the type is in an int), or "" (if the type is a string).

Comment: great! if you could upvote / mark as correct, I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "EmployeeAction.ACTION_CALL", place -1 (if the type is in an int), or "" (if the type is a string).